# How to initialize a nested Sorted Dictionary with Comparer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to create a dictionary of sorted dictionaries of which the sorted dictionaries arrange the keys in descending order. I'm trying like:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<long, string>> myDict= new Dictionary<string, SortedDictionary<long, string>>();
```

How do I set the comparer like:

```
Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x))
```

for the nested dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this code:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, SortedDictionary<long, string>>();
```

You're initializing an empty dictionary, which doesn't contain any nested dictionaries. To do the latter:

```
var comparer = Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));

var myDict = new Dictionary<string, SortedDictionary<long, string>
{
    // Add a SortedDictionary to myDict
    { "dict1", new SortedDictionary<long, string>>(comparer) 
        {
            // Add a key-value pair to the SortedDictionary
            { 123, "nestedValue" }
        }
    }
};
```